# Disable portrait mode on iPad to web app

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

Is it possible to disable portrait mode on iPad to web app?

I have developed a web app for iPad and iPhone to use css media quires. but I want to run this app only on landscape mode not portrait. So is there any solution how can I disable the portrait mode?

Comment: Is this a true web app i.e. are you using CSS media queries? or is it in a objective-c wrapper?

Comment: ya, I am using CSS media queries.

Comment: If you are using Media queries there is no way to disable portrait view however you can use a media query to re draw the design for the portrait dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can target :landscape and :portrait orientations with media queries, and can alter your design for each circumstance.