# Disable Portrait View in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My website is okay in the landscape view on tablets ( iPad etc ) but not in a portrait view.

Is there a way to Disable portrait View for tablets in Bootstrap ? So when the tablet is rotated it will not rotate the view.

I believe this can be done in native mobile applications, so it it possible on web with css/js etc ?

thanks.

Comment: So, what? The user will just have to crane their neck to use your landscape-mode web page on their portrait mode devices? Not a good solution. You should have asked how to make your website work in portrait mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable portrait mode on iPad to web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520980/disable-portrait-mode-on-ipad-to-web-app)

Comment: Yes i am disabling the portrait mode for a reason. The mentioned duplicate question is not related to bootstrap. I was hoping to see some thing which bootstrap provides by default.

Comment: Bootstrap isn't magical, it just uses media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is also just css and javascript. It's really the best solution to make your website work with portrait view instead of disabling it. If you are looking for something provided by Bootstrap, then you can do a lot using these media queries (based on Bootstrap's grid system).

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

I don't know for what reason you disable portrait view, but I'm pretty sure you can make it work. All css applied within the media query brackets only apply to the given screensize.

Comment: great thanks :), i wanted to disable it temporary as the site looked messed up in portrait view. I  will test your suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Force landscape in little screens on Boostrap. Source http://scala9simo.blogspot.com.ar/2015/04/trying-to-force-landscape-mode-on.html

```css
/* In CSS file */
@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .landscape-in-phone {  
        display:block;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
         min-width:460px;
    }  
}
```

```html
<!--In HTML file -->
<!--Page main container -->
<div class="landscape-in-phone">       
  <!--All body content here -->      
</div>
```